# What actually is a potential barrier in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, potential, schroedinger-equation, quantum-tunneling

**I'm new to quantum mechanics**, and I was wondering what actually is a **potential barrier** in quantum mechanics?

I understand that it is similar in a way to a hill in classical mechanics except that we get a decreasing exponential for too high energy for the probability density instead of a 0 and so on, but **experimentally** how to make a setup, for example, for the electron to go though a potential barrier?

Comment: the grid of a triode biased to a negative voltage relative to the cathode is a potential barrier between the cathode and the positive anode.

Comment: thank you! how to accept an answer on this website?

Comment: @nobody48sheldor You haven't gotten any answer. These are comments.

Comment: ah ok, well thanks for the help anyway, i m new to the site.

Comment: @hyportnex. Please, post your comment as an answer. It helps further searches in case of similar question.

Comment: Just to point out that such things are not only experimental set ups. Potential barriers exist in nature too. That's what alpha decay is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy example of a quantum mechanical potential barrier in an experimental setup is a scanning tunneling microscope. A voltage is applied between a solid crystal you want to scan and a tip. The space between tip and solid can be interpreted as a potential barrier, as removing an electron from the tip and placing it in this intermediate space would require energy, just like rolling a ball up a hill requires energy.